# Flutter how to disable clippath resize when keyboard appear?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

My Clippath height is change when keyboard appear.
Thank you so much.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add **`resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`** line in your **`Scaffold`** widget

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Comment: but keyboard will show forward textfield ;w;